# Toggle menu is not working in the mobile device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, togglebutton

My site toggle menu is not working in the mobile device. We have use the bootstrap v3.2.0 version.First click toggle menu is working but second time its not working.

Please give me the proper solution for this issue.Please check the following code and let me know where is the issue happening.The website has been developed into angular js, here is something will be conflicting with the js or may be causing an issue due to the bootstrap version or any.

Kindly go through the following html code which is used for the navbar-header menu and let me know where is the problem.

```
<div class="col-md-11">
    <div class="navbar-header" style="cursor:pointer;">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <!-- <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed dropdown-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">-->
        <!--class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse"-->
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-justified">
            <li class="phocl"> <a title="WATCH NOW" href="#portfolio">
                <div class="text-center hmain_menu" style="padding-bottom: 14px; padding-top: 15px;"> WATCH NOW </div>
                </a> 
            </li>
            <li class="phocl1"> <a title="INSPIRATION NATION" href="#services">
                <div class="text-center hmain_menu" style="padding-bottom: 14px; padding-top: 15px;"> INSPIRATION NATION </div>
                </a> 
            </li>
            <li class="phocl2"> <a title="NEWS" href="#news">
                <div class="text-center hmain_menu" style="padding-bottom: 14px; padding-top: 15px;"> NEWS </div>
                </a> 
            </li>
            <li class="phocl3"> <a id="addBookmark" title="BOOKMARK" href="#team">
                <!--id="bookmarkme" rel="sidebar" -->
                <div class="text-center hmain_menu" style="padding-bottom: 14px; padding-top: 15px;"> BOOKMARK </div>
                </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">
                <div class="send_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeModal" class="text-center" style="background-color:#50d07d;padding-bottom: 14px; padding-top: 30px;">
                SIGN IN
                </div>
                </a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

May be toggling or collapse the menu please help me resolve the Toggle navigation menu.

Comment: Can you post your code? Depending on what class the click is called off of, you might be hiding the element that can un-toggle it.

Comment: Please go through code updated into question above and help to fix out it.

Comment: Here's a fiddle. Please update it to demonstrate your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3qgazqwt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version

```
<!--- NAVIGATION -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/merimen-logo.png" class="img-responsive logo"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-justified">
        <li class="phocl text-center"> <a title="WATCH NOW" href="#portfolio">WATCH NOW</a></li>
        <li class="phocl1"><a title="INSPIRATION NATION" href="#services">INSPIRATION NATION</li>
        <li class="phocl2"><a title="NEWS" href="#news">NEWS</li>
        <li class="phocl3"><a id="addBookmark" title="BOOKMARK" href="#team">BOOKMARK</li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <div class="send_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeModal" class="text-center" style="background-color:#50d07d;padding-bottom: 14px; padding-top: 30px;">SIGN IN</div>
            </a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!--- NAVIGATION -->
```